# What is the purpose and usage of ASP.NET Handler (.ashx) files?

Tags: asp.net

What is the purpose of ASP.NET Handler (.ashx files) and how best can they be used?

Comment: The use can be an xml file render, an image render, a download file create on fly, a txt file for download create on fly...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758777/question-on-ashx-files-in-asp-net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An ASHX handler allows you a discrete http handler without the overhead of processing a page request (an ASPX file).

Comment: +1.  It's also called a Generic Handler and is very useful for things like building out REST services or emitting files.

Comment: thanks for the help, i added handler file - but how to run it from my default web page ?

Comment: You can call it like any other resource, e.g.: `<script src="MyHandler.ashx"></script>` assuming your handler returns the content type that resource is expecting...